# How do I check if there are any lines in a file beyond the header-line?

Tags: c#, file

I have following code:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(dir)
                .Skip(1);


foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var fields = line.Split(new Char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    date.Add(fields[0].Trim('\"'));
    if (fields.Length > 1)
        value.Add(Convert.ToDouble(fields[1].Trim('\"');
```

So I skip the headline (because it has "Date";"Value" written in it and start reading the lines underneath. That happens when I click a button and gets then shown in a chart.
It's possible that the file has only the headline and the rest is empty (so only one line) - How can I check that and maybe give a MessageBox with a warning? Something like:

```
if (---)
{
    MessageBox.Show("", "");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you could use [`Enumerable.Any<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(dir).Skip(1);

if (!lines.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("", "");
    return;
} 

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    //process line here
}
```

Comment: If I put the line between the foreach loop and the first var fields(...) line I get a warning that the file is empty even for files that aren't

Comment: You put it between `var lines = ...` and `foreach ...`. You don't want to check for each line if file is empty

Answer (score 2):

Check if lines has any element using `Any` extension method.

```
if (!lines.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("", "");
    return;
}
```

Note that this enumerates the list twice(With Any and foreach), but don't go any further beyond first element. So that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the lines. Enumerable so

```
if(!lines.Any()) 
{
   MessageBox.Show("", ""); 
}
```

Comment: lines isn't an array. so `Length` property will not be available.